# Displaying Error Messages in Salesforce Mobile when using the Chatter "Post" Action

Tags: chatter, mobile, error-messages, action

I want to prevent Chatter posts being created in certain conditions, displaying a relevant error message to users in the process.

In this following example, I have created a trigger that prevents anyone creating a post containing the word 'cake'.

```
trigger FeedItemTrigger on FeedItem (before insert) {
    for (FeedItem fi : trigger.new) {
        if (fi.Body.contains('cake')) {
            fi.addError('Please don\'t talk about cake, it makes everyone hungry!');
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when using Salesforce Classic and Lightning on a desktop:

[image: Feed Item Error Message in Salesforce Desktop]

But when using the "post" action in Salesforce Mobile, the behaviour changes. The FeedItem record is still prevented from being saved, but the error message is not displayed, instead just displaying the message "Invalid request.".

[image: Feed Item Error Message in Salesforce Mobile]

This is not very helpful to end users, who just think Salesforce Mobile is broken. Is there any way to get the full error message to display?

Comment: Looking at the success community, looks like this might be a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000o83eQAA , I was using ios, same thing for android devices too: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000o83yQAA . I seem to be the only one who has ever reported it (#mobilefirst), but I'll keep this post updated with the resolution